# How do I convert an IN clause with a correlated subquery to using a WITH statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to convert a correlated subquery into using a WITH clause.

Following is the query,

```
select count(*)
from item_master im
left join item_branch ib
on im.IMLITM = ib.IBLITM
left join supply_item si
on im.IMLITM = si.PCLITM
where true
and trim(ib.IBSTKT) in ('P', '7')
and trim(ib.IBVEND) in (
    select distinct sii.PCAN8
    from supply_item sii
    where true
    and trim(sii.PCMCU) in ('MXN09M', 'USNELP', 'USNELS')
    and sii.PCAN8 not in (60001, 60002, 60003, 60004, 60005, 60006, 60007, 60008, 60009, 60011)
    and sii.PCLITM = ib.IBLITM ---------> CORRELATED SUBQUERY COMES HERE
)
```

This is my attempt at it.

```
with tbl as (
select distinct sii.PCAN8 as PCAN, sii.PCLITM as PCLITM
    from supply_item sii
    where true
    and trim(sii.PCMCU) in ('MXN09M', 'USNELP', 'USNELS')
    and sii.PCAN8 not in (60001, 60002, 60003, 60004, 60005, 60006, 60007, 60008, 60009, 60011)
)
select count(*)
from item_master im
left join item_branch ib
on im.IMLITM = ib.IBLITM
left join tbl
on im.IMLITM = tbl.PCLITM
where true
and trim(ib.IBSTKT) in ('P', '7')
and trim(ib.IBVEND) in tbl.PCAN
```

I get an error saying `no such table: tbl.PCAN`. I am not sure why I am going wrong. I am providing a column to be checked on for the `in` clause just like before.

Comment: Not yet. My working hours got over for the day so I could not check. I can check this out after business gets back to me with some data for me to verify the answers posted.

Comment: No problem. Keep us posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a subquery at all, you should be able to replace your `IN` expression with a condition on the `LEFT JOIN`. Without sample data it's impossible to be 100% certain, but this should work:

```
with tbl as (
    select distinct sii.PCAN8 as PCAN, sii.PCLITM as PCLITM
    from supply_item sii
    where true
      and trim(sii.PCMCU) in ('MXN09M', 'USNELP', 'USNELS')
      and sii.PCAN8 not in (60001, 60002, 60003, 60004, 60005, 60006, 60007, 60008, 60009, 60011)
)
select count(*)
from item_master im
left join item_branch ib on im.IMLITM = ib.IBLITM
left join tbl on im.IMLITM = tbl.PCLITM and trim(ib.IBVEND) = tbl.PCAN
where true
  and trim(ib.IBSTKT) in ('P', '7')
```

Comment: @scientific_explorer I've updated my answer to not use a subquery at all. I *think* this should do what you want, without sample data it's impossible to be 100% certain.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be to select `PCAN` from the CTE:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT sii.PCAN8 AS PCAN, sii.PCLITM AS PCLITM
    FROM supply_item sii
    WHERE TRIM(sii.PCMCU) IN ('MXN09M', 'USNELP', 'USNELS') AND
          sii.PCAN8 NOT IN (60001, 60002, 60003, 60004, 60005, 60006, 60007, 60008, 60009, 60011)
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM item_master im
LEFT JOIN item_branch ib ON im.IMLITM = ib.IBLITM
LEFT JOIN tbl ON im.IMLITM = tbl.PCLITM
WHERE
    TRIM(ib.IBSTKT) IN ('P', '7') AND
    TRIM(ib.IBVEND) IN (SELECT PCAN FROM tbl);  -- change is here
```

Comment: But I'm still performing a subquery which I don't want to do.

Comment: There is not necessarily anything wrong this subquery.  Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: I am using a tool which uses SQL in the backend. The tool does not have the option to create subqueries. My only other alternative is to create temp tables and use that. I was thinking along those lines when I tried to create this `with` clause.

Comment: You can always just inline the CTE.  What would be wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong. My tool isn't capable of doing that - a subquery.

Comment: There is a way to write your query using a join to a subquery, if that would be acceptable to you.  But, the count might not be the same.